# How do I store numbers that matches in an array?

Tags: c++

I want to add the index of `arrayOfNumbers` that matched to `numToMatch` to an array. Not sure how to go about this. I'm new to C++. Any help would be appreciated ty.

```
int numToMatch[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int arrayOfNumbers[7] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int IndexThatMatched[4]; // Want to add to this Array.
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if(numToMatch[i] == arrayOfNumbers[j]) 
            {
                cout << "Num " << numToMatch[i] << " ";
                cout << "matches " << arrayOfNumbers[j];
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You almost finished it. `j+1` is the index you want when you start to account from 1. You have already to print `numToMatch[i]` and `arrayOfNumbers[j]`, then add another line to print the **index**.

Comment: I think my indexes are correct? I would like to know how to add what I matched to a new array called indexThatMatched.

Answer (score 0):

Added only two lines.

```
int numToMatch[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int arrayOfNumbers[7] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int IndexThatMatched[4]; // Want to add to this Array.
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        IndexThatMatched[i] = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if(numToMatch[i] == arrayOfNumbers[j]) 
            {
                cout << "Num " << numToMatch[i] << " ";
                cout << "matches " << arrayOfNumbers[j];
                cout << endl;
                IndexThatMatched[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If there was no match for `numToMatch[k]` then `IndexThatMatched[k]` will be -1.

In your example `IndexThatMatched` will be: `{1, 2, 3, 4}`.
That's because `numToMatch`'s elements are positioned in indices 1-4 of `arrayOfNumbers`.

Moreover, after that run, for any k in the safe range:
`numToMatch[k] == arrayOfNumbers[IndexThatMatched[k]]`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to learn C++ ditch the C-style arrays and start practising with containers. If you combine them with the functions in `<algorithm`> you can write something like this:

```
std::vector<int> MatchNums{1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> NumsToMatch{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::vector<int> MatchedNums;

for ( auto Number:NumsToMatch )
{
    auto Match = std::find( MatchNums.begin(), MatchNums.end(), Number );
    if ( Match != MatchNums.end() )
    {
        MatchedNums.push_back( *Match );
    }
}

for ( auto i:MatchedNums )
{   //Print out the found numbers:
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

There's a lot more ways of doing this by combining different algorithms and I encourage you to try and think of as many ways as you can and try them all out.